# Why are sorted dictionaries and lists slower to add, delete, and get values than unsorted?

Tags: c#, testing, dictionary, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I made some tests with: SortedDictionary, SortedList, and Dictionary (just to compare). The results were that Dictionary was much faster than those two others in adding, deleting and returning values based on key (100,000 pairs key+value in each dictionary).

Can someone tell me why SortedList and SortedDictionary are slower than Dictionary?

Comment: Because both of those, as the names suggest, are sorted each time an item is added to the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Take the simple example of a sorted list, based on an unsorted list.

Let us assume that the insertion time on the unsorted list at an arbitrary index is O(n/2) where n is the size of the list.  The reflects that on average, half of the list elements will have to be displaced to make room for the element being inserted.

Similarly, in this list, to remove an element from an arbitrary position is also O(n/2) because on average again half the elments will have to be moved to close the gap.

. . .

Now, imagine the same implementation, but with sorting.

The sorting will have to be done at insertion--it will have to find the position of the new element.  Since all previous elements are already sorted (we do it at insertion, so this is true), we can start scanning from the beginning.

This is a O(n/2) operation, before we even begin the insertion.  That is just to find the insertion point.

A better method, using binary search would give us O(log n) to find the insertion position, but still before paying the O(n/2) cost of doing the insertion itself.

If the cost of a scanning operation is s, and the cost of the insertion operation is m (for move), then the cost of the sorted insertion is:

```
s x O(log n) + m x (n/2)
```

However, an insertion operation on the unsorted list at an arbitrary position is only:

```
 m x (n /2)
```

This is a concrete example of the real reason why sorted operations take longer.

There is more to this type of theory, but that should be a start.

Comment: All log references in the above description are base 2, for the record.

Comment: add/remove to a `SortedDictionary` (as opposed to a `SortedList`, which you correctly analyzed) would be O(log(n)) not O(n).

Comment: @Servy I picked an easier example, mostly because I don't know the underlying implementation of C#'s `Dictionary` sorted dictionary type objects, and because I haven't done this type of analysis in 20 years and didn't want to look too stupid for mis-remembering something!

Comment: `Dictionary` is implemented as a has table.  `SortedDictionary` is a red/black tree.  `SortedList` is ... well, you analyzed it correctly.  It's also by far the least useful of the three.  I have, to date, never found a situation worth using one.  I use `Dictionary` objects *all the time* (i.e. usually daily, or close to it).  `SortedDictionary` I use much less often (personally), but it does have a place.

Answer (score 1):

Because these data structures do a sort *again* each time you add or remove values from them. So you get a performance hit when using them.

Comment: Not quite.  Some brute force naive implementations may do a full sort each time, but better implementations do not.  However, there must be effort spent maintaining the sorting invariant no matter what underlying implementation is.

Comment: Also *remove* may not need an internal reorganization.

Comment: Ok, so with adding and deleting you must be right that sorting makes it slower, but why I got also bad results for returning value(Key and Value were strings)?

Comment: @Berserker I have no idea what the question in your last comment means.

Comment: I ment, that times for getting value were much bigger.

Comment: @Berserker It's because you're doing a binary search, which is O(log(n)) as opposed to just hashing the value, which is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary simply throws the new entry at the end of the list.  All it has to do is track the location of the end of the list.  However, the SortedDictionary has to seek out the RIGHT spot in the list to put the new entry.  Obviously this requires some computational effort to do and will be slower than simply adding it to the end.

For deletes, both types of objects have to seek out the record you want to delete, but the Sorted types need to then evaluate the effect of deleting that record on their internal structure.  For example, a b-tree might need to re-balance it branches after the delete.  Again some amount of computation is needed to assess this.  Hence the difference in performance.

Comment: A `Dictionary` wouldn't add to the end, it would compute the hash of the key and then add the value to the index of that hash value's bucket.  It can do that in constant time (if there is a low hash collision rate).  A `SortedDictionary` needs to do a binary search to find the appropriate add/remove location (which is O(log(n)) time, but can do the actual add/remove in O(1) time (assuming the tree is balance, which it will be if it's a red/black tree).  `SortedList` is just a poor data structure to use; it'll need to move a bunch of elements up/down when adding/removing, so don't use it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I wrote Dictionary but had List on the brain.  Your extra detail is great.